# Isolating css classes in react project

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, frontend, less

I have to files bootstrap-iso.css and public-iso.css and component of name publicRoute which uses public-iso.css as it's base. However I have some parts in publicRoute that want to use bootstrap-iso, but without this public-iso css.

```
    const PublicRoute = ({ component: Component, sendMail, ...rest }) => {

    //Some code ...

     return(
    <div className="public-iso">

    //Some code ...
    
    <Route {...rest} component={(props) => (

    //Some code ...

    <Component {...props} />

    //Some code ...

    )}
    
    </div>
)}
```

And this Component have some part which need only bootstrap-iso.

```
const DirectComponent = () =>{

...Some code

return(
<div className="bootstrap-iso">

...some code

</div>

)}
```

Which finally leads to situation where:

```
<div className="public-iso">
   ...
   <div className="bootstrap-iso">
      <DirectComponent/>
   </div>
</div>
```

And I know, that I could just add public-iso class to all single components instead of adding it to whole PublicRoute component but it would be too redundant. So how can I exlude DirectComponent from range of public-iso class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excluding won't be possible but you might try overriding the css in this way

```
.public-iso .bootstrap-iso {
  ----
}
```

Since it will take higher precedence. Hope it helps.